# simple string mutation in php

Tags: php, arrays, string-matching

For my code I only want to have a string mutation if the the following word is "red". And no there is no logic behind it but it should be a simple case for a difficult one. 
So therefore I used `next()` but if the last word is "red" then it does not work.

My code:

```
$input = ['man', 'red', 'apple', 'ham', 'red'];
$endings = ['m', 'n'];

$shouldRemove = false;
foreach ($input as $key => $word) {
    // if this variable is true, it will remove the first character of the current word.
    if ($shouldRemove === true) {
        $input[$key] = substr($word, 1);
    }

    // we reset the flag 
    $shouldRemove = false;
    // getting the last character from current word
    $lastCharacterForCurrentWord = $word[strlen($word) - 1];

    if (in_array($lastCharacterForCurrentWord, $endings) && next($input) == "red") {
        // if the last character of the word is one of the flagged characters,
        // we set the flag to true, so that in the next word, we will remove 
        // the first character.
        $shouldRemove = true;
    }
}

var_dump($input);
```

As mentioned for the last "red" instead of getting "ed" I get "red". What should I do to get the desired output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can select the next key "manually":

```
$input = ['man', 'red', 'apple', 'ham', 'red'];
$endings = ['m', 'n'];

$shouldRemove = false;
foreach ($input as $key => $word) {
    // if this variable is true, it will remove the first character of the current word.
    if ($shouldRemove === true) {
        $input[$key] = substr($word, 1);
    }

    // we reset the flag 
    $shouldRemove = false;
    // getting the last character from current word
    $lastCharacterForCurrentWord = $word[strlen($word) - 1];

    if (in_array($lastCharacterForCurrentWord, $endings) && $input[$key+1] == "red") {
        // if the last character of the word is one of the flagged characters,
        // we set the flag to true, so that in the next word, we will remove 
        // the first character.
        $shouldRemove = true;
    }
}

var_dump($input);
```

> array(5) { [0]=> string(3) "man" [1]=> string(2) "ed" [2]=> string(5) "apple" [3]=> string(3) "ham" [4]=> string(2) "ed" }

Answer (score 1):

The reason it isn't working is that it relies on the next iteration of the loop to do what you need it to based on your evaluation in the current iteration. If the item you want to alter is the last item in the array, there will be no next iteration with which to alter it.

Instead of checking the following word, you can keep track of the previous word and use that.

```
$previous = '';
foreach ($input as $key => $word) {
    if ($word == 'red' && in_array(substr($previous, -1), $endings)) {
        $input[$key] = substr($word, 1);
    }
    $previous = $word;
}
```